# "Always use integral numbers for the width and height of your layer."

Tags: ios, calayer

In "Core Animation Programming Guide" of Mac Developer Library, it suggests that "Always use integral numbers for the width and height of your layer".

```
myLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
myLayer.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
```

Since CGRectMake and CGPointMake need parameters of CGFloat type, why should I use integral numbers here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Integral* here refers to the number itself, not the type. In other words, `200.0` is considered integral in this context, while `200.5` is not. The reason you should use integral numbers is to avoid placing layer bounds between physical pixels, which looks weird. (Of course you can’t really place anything between physical pixels, but the machine tries to approximate the look of it.)

Comment: what's the meaning of this line : "Integral here refers to the number itself, not the type."

Comment: “Integer” has two meanings: the mathematical one, a number without a fractional component, and the computer one, a way of storing numbers. When the documentation above talks about “integral numbers”, it means *integral* in the mathematical sense, “without fractional component”. It doesn’t matter that you store the number in a `float` later, the main point still holds: you’re not trying to place views between pixels.

Comment: First, thanks a lot. Then what's the reason CGRectMake and CGPointMake's parameters are CGFloat type?   In what situation we use numbers like 200.5, or we should never use numbers like 200.5?

Comment: It’s probably a combination of several factors. One of them is that the units used for view placement are not pixels. They used to correspond to pixels 1:1 on older, non-Retina devices, but nowadays each logical point takes two pixels – `CGPointMake(10, 10)` is actually (20, 20) in the physical coordinate space of a Retina device. In that case it makes sense to use fractions, for example 10.5 in logical points is 21 pixels on a Retina device.